# image having problem while loading in my php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a login page , where above the login box, a small image will is displayed below `logo.png` as `register.png`, the html is below:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="center"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="378" height="90" class="picture" /></div></td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="42%"><div class="login-box">
<div class="login-border">
<div class="login-style">
    <div class="login-header">
        <div class="logo clear">
            <div align="center" style="margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/register.png" alt="" width="235" height="29" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the `logo.png` is displaying, but the `register.png` is not displaying, the height and width and all are correct.
Can anyone tell what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: can you please check that you have entered correct name and path?

Comment: i have entered the correct path, the website showing failed to load resource, but the file is correct only

Comment: make sure you have the image in folder "images"

Comment: it is in folder..

Comment: is this issue with class wich you have to add  class="picture" and not in register

Comment: please check is there any class which have CSS with display: none

Comment: Can you send screenshot of developers console showing the error

Answer (score 0):

check you last  closing tag. It is missing over here.

Also try to use exact path if it does not work properly.

Ex C:\laragon\www\path-to-your-file

Ensure the file type is also same .png .jpg might be one cause too

Answer (score 0):

1. You first verify the name of the image and image path.
2. Make sure you are mentioned image available right path.
3. Test with various CSS height and width, also try without CSS.
4. Remove all already declared CSS classes (it may have any hide attribute).

I hope you this going to help you.